# conditional link library when switch build from simulator to device

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application using the third party library from my customer. They provide me two static library one for simulator and one for device. How can I change setting to allow me set to project setting to build against right library when project change configuration? can i use --framework flag? if it is, how I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way might be to merge the two libraries with [lipo](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html). The linker will choose the appropriate architecture's code during the build. This [blog post](http://dev.byteclub.com/blog/1-iphone-sdk/48-how-to-almost-create-your-own-iphone-os-framework) discusses the process (in the context of a much more complete pseudo-framework setup).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211854/xcode-conditional-file-linking-compilation-based-on-configuration) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348051/creating-static-library-for-iphone).